# how to calculate approximate height of line in below image?

Tags: image

[image: image to segment]

```
 To segment above image i want to use line height. I don't know even any algorithm for   this. I want a useful link pls help..

 just i want an efficient algorithm link for this.....

 I shall be very thankful to you for this..
```

// i ahve tried till now

```
 function [avmax avmin avgwidth]=firstsvg(Imag)
 %Imag=imread('D:\THAPAR\poj\images\ndpj.jpg');
 imtool(Imag);
 G=Imag;
 %xlswrite('G.xlsx',Imag(:,:,1));
 [y,x]=size(G);  % y dentoes rows and x denotes columns
 T=160;%sum(sum(I))/(y*x)%T dentoes threshhold value - i.e avg
 HYT=zeros(1,1);
 GY=zeros(y,1);  %single column of zeros              
 for j=1:y   
     for i=1:x
        if (G(j,i)<T)         
         GY(j,1)=GY(j,1)+1;  % count of no. of black pixel
       end    
    end
 end
 for c=1:y
    if (GY(c,1)> min)
     min = GY(c,1);
     gt(ce,1)=GY(c,1);
     ce=ce+1;
    end
 end
 dgt=zeros(ce,1);
 for b=1:(ce-2)
   dgt(b,1)= gt(b+1,1)- gt(b,1);
 end
 mdgt= mean(dgt);
 avgwidth= thyt;
 avmax =thyt;
 avmin = gt(1,1);

 just i want an algorithm link to calculate line height ???
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have image of M x N dimension where M is row and N is column. Perform logical OR for pixels in row. If you get 1, then you have atleast one black pixel in particular row.
Just see the number of consecutive 1's you are getting, it will be the approximate height of each sentence.

Comment: BUT IF WE NOT GET ANY ZERO BECOZ OF LINE COINCIDES WITH EACH OTHER AT SOME POINT... I HAVE ALREADY TRIED THAT

Comment: When you down vote, you need to explain the reason. I just suggested you to try this. If you already did, thats just great.

Also, may be then rather than doing logical OR, you could add up the binaries and allow minimum filter lever (lets say, X overlap is allowed), then if your SUM > X then do not treat it as line, otherwise if SUM < X, then it is blank line. To find out X, is really backtracking or you just try up few numbers which fits your case.

Comment: sorry sir, i had made a mistake. its now locked. pls change your reply i will undo that.

Comment: The answer you gave in comments is already tried...actually i want to ask link for some algorithm for this with better results...